# Disabling an input box conditionally using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sudoku

I'm building out a Sudoku game using just jQuery. I have most of the logic built out (it's still pretty rough at this point - planning to refactor after I get this last piece). I'm stuck on when I generate a board, I'd like to disabled those specific input fields. Here is the section of code I'm using to build out the board:

```
var context = this;

$td = $('<td>')
    .append($('<input>')
    .data('row', i)
    .data('col', j)
    .data('region', region)
    .val(function(){
        var prefillValue = easyGame[i][j];
        if(prefillValue !== -1){
            context.currentMatrix.rows[i].push(prefillValue);
            context.currentMatrix.columns[j].push(prefillValue);
            context.currentMatrix.regions[region].push(prefillValue);
            return prefillValue;
        }
    })
    .on('keyup', $.proxy(this.validateInput, this))
    .on('click', $.proxy(this.captureInput, this)));
```

High level view:
What's happening is I have an array of arrays stored in the easyGame variable. This variable contains the prebuilt number locations for the "easy" board.

I then do a lookup on the easyGame variable for each row and column and if there's a value (aka as long as the lookup on easyGame isn't -1) I set that as the value of the current input box that I'm building out. If the lookup comes back as -1, the input value is left blank.

The code above works fine (it's pretty slow and clunky but the wireframe is there for now).

Where I'm getting stuck, is I want to disable only the input boxes where a value is present on the initial build (aka the code above).

I think I'm overthinking this but is there a way to apply the disabled property .prop('disabled', true) conditionally - aka when the lookup isn't -1?

Thanks in advance and if there's any more information that's needed, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here's the answer for anyone else trying to do this:

```
.prop("disabled", easyGame[i][j] !== -1 ? true : false)
```